# GTK: undefined reference to `cairo_surface_set_device_scale'

Tags: qt, gtk, cairo

I'm trying to install a software called [bgslibrary](https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary/wiki/Graphical-User-Interface:-QT) with GUI (QT). `cmake` generates the build files without a problem. But when I do `make`, I get the following error related to `libgtk` and`cairo`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `cairo_surface_set_device_scale'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5.4.1, I also have Anaconda installed as Python distribution. I googled a bit and found out that some people solved the problem by removing their `$HOME/anaconda/lib` directory from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because somehow Anaconda might be interfering with the`gtk` libraries. I tried this but it didn't work for me.

I also checked the versions and symlinks of `libgtk` and `cairo` on my system.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9
```

and `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev` yields:

```
libcairo2-dev is already the newest version (1.14.6-1).
```

Could there be a mismatch between the `libgtk` and `cairo` versions? I remember encountering this error also for other softwares that required `gtk` so I was wondering if anyoned had similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that I get the same error also when I try to start Eclipse:

`/usr/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale`

`/opt/eclipse/eclipse: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale`

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same error either in gedit & eclipse.

The solution was changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to use

libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2 -> libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11512.0

libcairo.so.2-> libcairo.so.2.11512.0

instead of version 11200 of libcairo-script-interpreter and libcairo
 which couse the problem

libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2 -> libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11200.18

libcairo.so.2 -> libcairo.so.2.11200.18